# Cortar imagen y mostrarla. En Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Quisiera obtener un trozo de la siguiente imagen, y mostrarla.

Por lo que he podido investigar, puedo usar la libreria image (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image/versions/1.1.4#-readme-tab-)
con la función **Image copyCrop(Image src, int x, int y, int w, int h); **

No encuentro como integrar esa función en mi codigo. Y si guardo el resultado en una variable no se como mostrarla por ejemplo en un Container.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo:

```html
import 'dart:io' as Io;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as copy;



Image imagen = readPng(new Io.File('assets/imagesayuda2.png').readAsBytesSync());

//Image copyCrop(Image src, int x, int y, int w, int h);

Image imagenCortada = copyCrop(imagen,20,20,10,10);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu código para ver lo que tienes y darte sugerencias

Comment: Listo ya agregue el trozo de codigo donde creo la variable imagen de tipo Image. Y la variable imagenCortada no se como agregarla a un Container.

Comment: imagesayuda2.png es la que pusiste en la pregunta no? la puedes agregar en full resolución , con un link para acceder a ella

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjMsfrI5LbhAhXFUt8KHX0EAJsQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19779045%2Fhow-can-i-use-a-sprite-to-specify-the-pushpin-png-i-want-to-use-in-a-map%3Fnoredirect%3D1%26lq%3D1&psig=AOvVaw2-ePIjNP3kFNuuTTaQDxQ8&ust=1554479238061734

Comment: Ese es el link para acceder.

Comment: parece que hay un bug al momento de mostrar la imagen cortada , por el tipo de codec  https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/issues/107

Comment: No conoceras alguna otra forma de hacerlo? existe una libreria que se llama sprites que utiliza este tipo de imagenes. pero no encuentro el metodo para capturar.

Comment: Tengo que revisar, lo que quieres es sacar una imagen basado en coordenadas y mostrar solo esa parte no?

Comment: Si exactamente. simplente recortar el espacio que necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una forma de hacerlo solo con `CustomPainter`, el ejemplo queda así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código lo puedes revisar aquí : https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter-samples/blob/master/lib/split_image/main_split_image.dart

Dentro del Painter estoy dibujando la imagen de la siguiente forma:

```
    canvas.drawImageRect(image, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, Paint());
```

Y para cortarla , antes de esa línea se aplica clipRect al canvas

```
    canvas.clipRect(Rect.fromLTWH(x, y, width, height));
```

Comment: Excelente diego. Muchas gracias. Voy a probarlo.

Comment: Excelente @diegoveloper ..!

Comment: diegoveloper quisiera realizarte una consulta via correo, se que eres el unico que tiene la respuesta de mi duda sobre flutter. me puedes escribir? jesus.cortez.1991@gmail.com

Comment: Justamente para eso está StackOverflow :), puedes crear tu pregunta y poner el link aquí para que todos podamos ayudarte

Comment: Tienes razón, 

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287814/seguridad-app-flutter

ya lo agregue. En cuanto puedas echale una ojeada. de verdad ando medio desesperado.